# Can't place Voronoi texture evenly

Tags: texturing

[image]
I am trying to place the Voronoi Chebuchev grid on the modified cubes. The problem is in those light areas that randomly appear when I change the Size of the texture. Is there any other procedural way (non UV) to place this texture on the meshes more evenly? (like a projection by X and Y axes for example)
Later I'm using both: color and distance outputs of the voronoi node. So they need to match

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file so that someone understand why it doesn't work as it should?

Comment: I dont think it  doesnt work as it should. I mean, try to add any concave or convex to the standard cube and you'll get the same result. Anyways, I've added the file

Comment: someone proposes here a procedural grid texture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsZoJBeAWGc ... but maybe someone here will know how to do

Comment: it works a s it should. the problem here is that you are working with a 3D texture. you are not projecting a grid of rectangles onto your surface but your surface cuts through a 3 dimensional grid of cubes. the lighter parts appear whenever the surface hits the white boundary between the cubes in xy direction.